# how to represent a number value as a string in python?

Tags: python, string

In Python, how can I represent an integer value (<256) as a string?  For example:

```
i = 10
```

How can I create a string "s" that is one-byte long, and the byte has the value 10?

to clarify,  I do not want a string "10".  I want a string that its 1st (and only) byte has the value of 10.

by the way, I cannot create the string statically:

```
s = '\x0A'
```

because the value is not pre-defined. It is a dynamic number value.

Comment: `'\xA'` is a syntax error, presumably you meant `'\x0A'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `chr()` function as:

```
>>> chr(60)
'<'
>>> chr(97)
'a'
>>> chr(67)
'C'
```

To convert back use `ord()` funtion as:

```
>>> ord('C')
67
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2.x, you want:

```
s = chr(10)
```

In Python 3.x, strings are Unicode, so you want:

```
s = bytes([10])
```

Comment: Yeah but it's Unicode, so probably not what you *really* want.

Comment: Why not? The OP has specified that if they'd hardcode the string they'd use `'\x0A'`, not `b'\x0A'`. It is not clear what version they are using, in any case.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you just use `chr`?

```
chr(10)
Out[41]: '\n'

chr(255)
Out[42]: '\xff'
```

Answer (score 0):

Found another answer using struct module working for Python 2:

import struct 
struct.pack('B', i)